# changing of app version windows phone 8 sdk

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Changing app version (1.4.0.0) in WMAppManifest.xml but when publish on store it show 1.0.0.0 while uploading \ updating the app in windows phone store and also while update the app, I need to “add new” in update app section and all related information should be filled up, please let us know is any alternate way to avoid to fill all relevant data again & again.

thanks,
Sunil

Answer (score 2):

When you update you app for Different versions, you upload a different .Xap file each time so the information that you neeeded to fill is for your new .xap file's Description along with `Version number` that is the Description for new .xap file and About the Key Updates what you have done in current submission and the new Screens for displaying about new update so There is no way to retain same 
infomarmation that you have filled before for old versions. `everytime when you upload new version .xap, You needed to fill it again for your new Update Version.`

Answer (score 0):

When you update your App in Windows Phone Store. You should choose **'Replace'**, and after the app uploaded. You should modify the version shown on that page to your app version, like 1.4.0.0 **manual**.